# Characterization of collections of Galois elements by their action on distinguished collections of algebraic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

I recently asked the following question ([Galois elements determined by action on $n$-th roots of rationals?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/329976/galois-elements-determined-by-action-on-n-th-roots-of-rationals)). Somehow I could not log back into that account, and instead have ended up with a new one! Many thanks for the helpful comments on that question; they confirmed what I had thought was the case but wasn't sure, as well as clarified and corrected it.

My motivation in asking the question was certain comments I had come across to the effect that no element of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}
}/\mathbb{Q})$ other than the identity and complex conjugation could be named, i.e., fully characterized because, I assume, in order to do so one would have to specify its action on all algebraic numbers compatibly with all their algebraic relations.

In lieu of full characterization I wondered if it might be possible and useful to characterize *collections* of Galois elements by properties of their actions on certain distinguished collections of algebraic numbers, e.g., $\mathcal{R} = \{r^{1/n}: r \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. One could, e.g., ask which elements of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ fix $\mathcal{R}$, and study their properties further.

Is that sensible, possible and useful?

Comment: There is already a name for Galois elements whose behavior has been very fruitful in number theory: Frobenius elements or conjugacy classes associated to prime ideals. They are not as down-to-earth as complex conjugation ("Frobenius at infinity"), but they are dense in Galois groups over $\mathbf Q$, which is very nice.